# Does there exist a candidate for 'holomorphic' instanton Floer homology?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, floer-homology

The Euler characteristic of instanton Floer homology agrees with the Casson invariant. Thomas introduced the notion of holomorphic Casson invariant, defined using the holomorphic Chern-Simons functional. Is there any reasonable way a 'holomorphic' instanton Floer homology might exist?